# Integration with Bullhorn SOAP webservice API using Coldfusion

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion

I'm starting to work on the Bullhorn SOAP webservice integration using Coldfusion 8. I'm having problems with authentication - getting the session.
I've tried doing it like someone did [here](http://supportforums.bullhorn.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=9301&p=42111&hilit=coldfusion#p42111):

```
<cfset   session_arg   =   structnew()>
<cfset   session_arg.username   =   'xxxxxx'>
<cfset   session_arg.password   =   'xxxxxxx'>
<cfset   session_arg.apiKey      =   'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'>

<cfinvoke
           webservice         =   "https://api.bullhornstaffing.com/webservices-2.0/?wsdl"
           method            =   "startSession"
           returnvariable      =   "bhSession"
           argumentcollection   =   "#session_arg#">
</cfinvoke>
```

I've replaced the 1.1 endpoint with 2.0 webservice endpoint.
startSession() works all right, but I'm supposed to get session value using getSession(), but it's not available in the object returned - it's a function from parent class.

[image]

I've tried using bhSession.super.getSession() but that didn't work either.

I'd be grateful for any suggestion how to approach this integration:

- should I leave cfinvoke/createObject completely and continue with
  CFHTTP and making the soap envelopes by hand?
- or maybe use some Java library to do the integration?
- or maybe use the 1.1 version of the API?

---

SOAP response I get using soapUI:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:startSessionResponse xmlns:ns2="http://apiservice.bullhorn.com/">
         <return>
            <session>THE_SESSION_VAR</session>
            <corporationId>COPRPORATION_ID</corporationId>
            <userId>USER_ID</userId>
         </return>
      </ns2:startSessionResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

All is fine there. Seems that the manual way would be the right solution.

Thanks for your help.
Lucas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out in the end.

Should have used GetSOAPResponse to get the actual response.

Example code if someone is interested:

```
<cfscript>
    webservice = createObject("webservice", "https://api.bullhornstaffing.com/webservices-2.0/?wsdl");
    webservice.startSession(myUsername, myPassword, myAPIKey);
    sessionResult = GetSOAPResponse(webservice);
</cfscript>
```

The sessionResult will contain the XML needed.